# Seting up Basic auth with swagger-ui-express

Tags: express, swagger

I am trying to set up basic auth with swagger-ui-express. I am passing an options object to do so as indicated in the docs but it does not work.
I can't tell if its because the structure of my options object is wrong or if it's because of something else. Thank you very much in advance!

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const dashboardDocument = require('../dashboardAPI.json');

var options = {
  swaggerOptions: {
    authAction: {
      Basic: {
        name: "user1",
        schema: {
          type:"application/json",
          in: "header",
          name: "Authorization",
        },
        value: "Basic bG9naW46cGFzc3dvcmQ="
      }
    }
  }
}

router.use("/", swaggerUi.serve);
router.get("/", swaggerUi.setup(dashboardDocument, options));
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two things, the first one is your swaggerUi options.

I think you have do some mistakes in keys.

```js
const swaggerUiOptions = {
  swaggerOptions: {
    basicAuth: {
      name:   'Authorization',
      schema: {
        type: 'basic',
        in:   'header'
      },
      value:  'Basic <user:password>'
    }
  }
}
server.use('/v1/swagger', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec, swaggerUiOptions))
```

The seconde is your swagger definition you have to add a `securitySchemes` to use your basic authorization and use it in your route definition. https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/

I use swagger Jsdoc and for me it's:

```js
components: {
  securitySchemes: {
    basicAuth: {
      type:   'http',
      scheme: 'basic'
    }
  }
}
```